# How to create a Launch Group programmatically in Eclipse, I need it to be part of my Eclipse PlugIn

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, launch, launcher

#### Issue:

I am developing an Eclipse plugin, where I need to launch multiple entities. I figured that Group Launch was the best way to do it. I can easily create a Group Launch Manually(**Run Configurations > Launch Group**)

However, I want this Group Launch configuration to be a part of my plugin itself. So that the end user doesn't have to create it manually.

Is there any way to import and use this configuration as a part of my plugin. So that the end user can just **Right-Click on a project > Run As > My Group Launch**

#### What I tried:

1) I can export it as a ***.launch*** file, and import it. But can't figure out a way to make it a part of my plugin.

2) Eclipse does provides an extension point: ***org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroups*** but not enough documentation on how to actually use it.

3) I can use normal Launch's code to invoke the Entities manually. But I am not sure if its the best or valid way to do it.

Comment: The Platform Plug-in Developer Guide section of the help has a large section in the Programmer's Guide. Look at 'Program debug and launch support'.

Comment: Thanks, @greg-449, I will check it out..